# JQM:ios prev/next makes style changed

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have use phonegap+jquerymobile to develop my mobile application.
I noticed condition below:
(step.1)I tap an textarea to input something 
(step.2)I tap a select button with ios form control(prev/next), then the style change greatly. All the elements has been zoomed in.

I test my application in andriod. However, everything works as expect.The condition only shows in IOS.

Any idea? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent zoom when input element is selected use this viewport meta tag:

Android:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

iOS:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it myself and found that it's a bug in jquery mobile. After updating jquery mobile to 1.3, all thing worked well in ios.